# Cant use UUID datatype when creating type in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, uuid, pgadmin-4

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
create DOMAIN Rating SMALLINT CHECK (VALUE>0 AND VALUE<=5);
create TYPE Feedback(
student_id uuid ,
rating Rating,
feedback TEXT
);
```

its giving me this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "uuid"
LINE 4: student_id uuid ,
                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 138
```

Im using pgadmin4 and UUID datatype works fine when creating table but its giving me error when im creating type.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need the `uuid-oosp` extension to use the data type `uuid`.

Comment: You're trying to create a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html#id-1.9.3.94.5.5) using [scalar type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html#id-1.9.3.94.5.8) syntax. `CREATE TABLE name AS (...)` is for composite types, `CREATE TYPE name AS ENUM (...)` for enumerated, `CREATE TYPE name AS RANGE (...)` for range, `CREATE TYPE name (...)` for scalar.

Answer (score 0):

The command [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) requires the `AS` keyword:

`CREATE TYPE feedback` **`AS`** `(...);`

(As opposed to [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).)

This is unrelated to pgAdmin or the `uuid` data type.